# Is there an optimized combination of `span` and `foldl'`, or will the combination be optimized by GHC?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, fold

Suppose I want to add up all the elements of a list up to but not including the first negative number and return the number and the rest of the list. The simple way to do this is

```
addPos l = s `seq` (s,back)
  where
    (front, back) = span (>= 0) l
    s = sum front
```

where the `seq` should ensure that no one accidentally builds a huge thunk by forcing the back before the sum.

I'm curious, however, whether GHC is smart enough to avoid creating the intermediate front list. Also, could someone explain how (if at all) it figures out that it can accumulate strictly in sum? The Prelude definition uses foldl rather than foldl', and the GHC definition *looks* equivalent.

Comment: "Also, could someone explain how (if at all) it figures out that it can accumulate strictly in sum?"
foldl is inlined and plus is strict.  The strictness analyser does everything else.  foldl' is rarely needed for this reason.

Comment: span is more or less 'takeWhile' p xs, 'dropWhile' p xs. But why do you need to use span if you got a performance problem with your addPlus ? Study the http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html as jberryman says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we talk about the compiler optimizing away intermediate lists usually we're talking about "fusion" implemented in GHC's `RULES` pragma; you can reas about how that works, and which list functions are "good consumers" and "producers" [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html).

Unfortunately it doesn't look like `span` is a "good producer". You can see for yourself by asking to look at GHC's core output and get a list of the rules that fired with `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-module-prefixes -dsuppress-uniques -ddump-core-stats -ddump-inlinings -ddump-rule-firings test.hs`

Here is a cleaned up output:

```
Rule fired: Class op >=
Rule fired: SPEC Data.List.sum
Inlining done: geInt{v r3n} [gid]
Inlining done: sum_sum1{v rkV} [gid]
Inlining done: span{v r1Q} [gid]
Inlining done: sum_sum'1{v rl6} [gid]

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 24, types: 27, coercions: 0}

addPos1 :: Int -> Bool
addPos1 = \ (ds :: Int) -> case ds of _ { I# x -> >=# x 0 }

addPos [InlPrag=INLINE[0]] :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])
addPos =
  \ (w :: [Int]) ->
    case $wspan @ Int addPos1 w of _ { (# ww1, ww2 #) ->
    case $wsum' ww1 0 of ww3 { __DEFAULT -> (I# ww3, ww2) }
    }
```

You can see we call some sort of rewritten/specialized `span`, followed by a `sum`.

You might see if the `vector` library can fuse them, or see how the performance compares for fun.

Comment: Thanks for the research! The next question, of course, is whether there's a standard function for combining `foldl` with `span`, or whether I just need to roll my own.